# Merging columns in sliding window steps

Tags: bash, awk, gsub

I have a tab delim file

```
NC_044998.1     3778    0       CC      0       CC      0       CC      0       CC      1       CT      0       CC      0       CC      0       CC      0       CC      1       CT      0      CC       var     heterozygous    varvar  9       0.818182        2       0.181818        refref  refref  refref  refref  refdev  refref  refref  refref  refref  refdev  refref  homo    homo   homo     homo    het     homo    homo    homo    homo    het     homo    9       0       2       0       9       2
NC_044998.1     3787    0       CC      0       CC      1       CG      0       CC      0       CC      0       CC      0       CC      0       CC      0       CC      0       CC      0      CC       var     heterozygous    varvar  10      0.909091        1       0.0909091       refref  refref  refdev  refref  refref  refref  refref  refref  refref  refref  refref  homo    homo   het      homo    homo    homo    homo    homo    homo    homo    homo    10      0       1       0       10      1
```

where columns `$32-$43` have on kind of info (ref/dev) and columns `$43-$54` another (homo/het)
I wanna combine them so that col `$32` is merged with the col at `$32` + 11 = `$43` and appended to the end of the file, then move `i` + 1, so that `$33$44` is merged and appended, then `$34$45`, and so on.
The output would look like

```
NC_044998.1     3778    0       CC      0       CC      0       CC      0       CC      1       CT      0       CC      0       CC      0       CC      0       CC      1       CT      0      CC       var     heterozygous    varvar  9       0.818182        2       0.181818        refref  refref  refref  refref  refdev  refref  refref  refref  refref  refdev  refref  homo    homo   homo     homo    het     homo    homo    homo    homo    het     homo    9       0       2       0       9       2   refrefhomo  refrefhomo  refrefhomo  refrefhomo  refdevhet  refrefhomo  refrefhomo  refrefhomo  refrefhomo  refdevhet refrefhomo
NC_044998.1     3787    0       CC      0       CC      1       CG      0       CC      0       CC      0       CC      0       CC      0       CC      0       CC      0       CC      0      CC       var     heterozygous    varvar  10      0.909091        1       0.0909091       refref  refref  refdev  refref  refref  refref  refref  refref  refref  refref  refref  homo    homo   het      homo    homo    homo    homo    homo    homo    homo    homo    10      0       1       0       10      1   refrefhomo  refrefhomo  refdevhet  refrefhomo  refrefhomo  refrefhomo  refrefhomo  refrefhomo  refrefhomo  refrefhomo  refrefhomo
```

I can one by one by

```
 cut -f32,43 file | sed 's/ //g' | paste file - > file.tmp
```

but It generates 11 tmp files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN {
   FS=OFS="\t"
}
{
   for (i=32; i<43; ++i)
      $0 = $0 OFS $i $(i+11)
} 1' file
```

```
NC_044998.1 3778    0   CC  0   CC  0   CC  0   CC  1   CT  0   CC  0   CC  0   CC  0   CC  1   CT  0   CC  var heterozygous    varvar  9   0.818182    2   0.181818    refref  refref  refref  refref  refdev  refref  refref  refref  refref  refdev  refref  homo    homo    homo    homo    het homo    homo    homo    homo    het homo    9   0   2   0   9   2   refrefhomo  refrefhomo  refrefhomo  refrefhomo  refdevhet   refrefhomo  refrefhomo  refrefhomo  refrefhomo  refdevhet   refrefhomo
NC_044998.1 3787    0   CC  0   CC  1   CG  0   CC  0   CC  0   CC  0   CC  0   CC  0   CC  0   CC  0   CC  var heterozygous    varvar  10  0.909091    1   0.0909091   refref  refref  refdev  refref  refref  refref  refref  refref  refref  refref  refref  homo    homo    het homo    homo    homo    homo    homo    homo    homo    homo    10  0   1   0   10  1   refrefhomo  refrefhomo  refdevhet   refrefhomo  refrefhomo  refrefhomo  refrefhomo  refrefhomo  refrefhomo  refrefhomo  refrefhomo
```

Comment: Thank you! And this should bring my text processing week to an end!

Comment: Your questions have been pretty engaging

Answer (score 1):

Mostly logic wise an answer like @anubhava sir's. With variables and a small additional logic of adding digits to end of line with difference of maximum field number with starting field number.

```
awk -v startFieldnum="32" -v tillFieldnum="43" '
BEGIN{
   FS=OFS="\t"
   diff=(tillFieldnum-startFieldnum)
}
{
   for (i=startFieldnum; i<tillFieldnum ; ++i)
      $0 = $0 OFS $i $(i+diff)
} 1' Input_file
```